# Upgraded from MVC3 to 5, now Application_AuthenticateRequest no longer receives the auth'd requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've upgraded an old project containing .asmx files from MVC 3 to MVC 5, and now the Application_AuthenticateRequest handler in Global.asax no longer is seeing all requests.  It sees a client's initial requests, my code returns the 401 with BASIC auth desired, but when the client responds with the Auth header set, Application_AuthenticateRequest never gets the 2nd request.  I've used Fiddler to verify this.

Moreover, something -- likely the MVC framework -- is adding a BASIC auth of its own with realm='localhost' on the initial response, so my app's initial response has the BASIC auth header twice.

How do I get the Application_AuthenticateRequest  handler to once again see all the requests it used to?

EDIT TO ADD: I get the same behavior on a brand-new MVC5 project.  But the issue only happens for Local IIS; the code works fine on IIS EXPRESS.

I've also tried my code on a fresh server install, whose IIS settings are normal. Same issue.

... Application_BeginRequest *is* called both times, so the 2nd request does make it to the app.  So I'm assuming MVC5 added a new feature that's "helping"?

Comment: Are you using the `[Authorize]` action filter either directly on a controller or as a global filter?

Comment: No. There's only one controller and it's basically for heartbeat / debugging.

Comment: Does your `<modules>` section in the web.config have the `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` set to true?

Comment: It is set to True.
  
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>

Comment: Do you have basic authentication disabled and anonymous authentication enabled in IIS? IIS is likely interdicting your request. If you want to do custom basic auth, you'll need to have basic authentication disabled for IIS. I'm going to guess that's why it works in IIS express the configuration of those 2 isapi modules is different / nonexistent in IIS-express

Comment: THANK YOU.  I didn't know I had to *disable* Basic Auth to use it. Counter-intuitive...

Comment: It makes sense when you think about it. IIS's basic auth runs at a level lower than ASP.NET, so IIS wants to prioritize its implementation. Unfortunately its implementation is nearly worthless because of its coupling to active directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have basic authentication disabled and anonymous authentication enabled in IIS? IIS is likely interdicting your request. If you want to do custom basic auth, you'll need to have basic authentication disabled for IIS. I'm going to guess that's why it works in IIS express the configuration of those 2 isapi modules is different / nonexistent in IIS-express –  Chris Marisic

Answer (score 0):

For all requests, I think you'd want to use `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` instead of `Application_AuthenticateRequest`

Comment: If it can't reach Authenticate to begin with, how can it ever reach PostAuthenticate?